# Visualize any size of image without distortions flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I hope the title is clear.
I need to visualize an image as background picture but it's dynamic, the user can change it when he/she wants.

The problem is that I would like to fit it in some box (Container, SizedBox....) without distorsions, compressions...The picture must be clear and good to look.

Do you know how I can do this?

I tried with :

```
SizedBox(
      width : _screenWidth,
      height: _customLabelsHeight,
      child : SizedBox.expand(
        child : ClipRRect (
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          child : _backGroundPicture==null
            ? new Image.asset('assets/images/io.png'
             )
             : _backGroundPicture,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

But this isn't what I'm looking for because some pictures are cut, bigger, smaller...The size changes and sometimes pictures are weird...

"_backGroundPicture" comes from "ImagePicker" :

```
var _backGroundPicture;

Future changeBackgroundPicture() async {
      var newImage2 = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: 
      ImageSource.gallery);

      setState(() {
        _backGroundPicture=newImage2;
      });
  }
```

Update : the line with the error

```
image : _backGroundPicture==null
                    ? new AssetImage('assets/images/io.png')
                    : _backGroundPicture,
```

Where _backGroundPicture is : 
    var _backGroundPicture;
And all is child of gestureDetector that onTap has : 
    GestureDetector(
              onTap : changeBackgroundPicture,
    .
    .
    .
    Future changeBackgroundPicture() async {
     var newImage2 = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: 
     ImageSource.gallery);

```
 setState(() {
   _backGroundPicture = newImage2;
 });
}
```

Comment: does the api version change affect your code [image_picker 0.6.7](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) ?

Comment: I had the 0.6.5, now I upgraded it but the problem is the same.

Comment: changed `pickImage()` to `getImage()` ?

Comment: Yeah, AndroidStudio told me to change "PickImage" with"getImage" but however it says : " Instance member 'getImage' can't be accessed using static access. "

Comment: You will have to instantiate `final picker = ImagePicker();` and use `picker.getImage(..)`

Comment: When I change image it says : " type 'PickedFile' is not a subtype of type 'ImageProvider<dynamic>' "

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `setState((){})` to have

```
setState(() {
      _backGroundPicture = Image.file(File(pickedFile.path));
    });
```

Comment: Which are the benefits?

Comment: Almost resolved, the the only problem is that : "_File" is not a subtype of 'ImageProvider<dynamic>'. What does it means?